# Access define plugin variables in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

How to access webpack.config define plugin variables in angularjs files (controllers, services..)? Do I need to import webpack or something similar...and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define some value as

```
const ENV = 'development';

plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
      }
    })
]
```

And use the defined value in js file as:

```
const ENV = process.env.ENV;
```

Comment: @DejanDimitrijevic would you mind accepting the answer ;P

Comment: 'no-process-env' need to be off in .eslintrc.js